# C++ meta-programming: A template parameter which *must* inherit an abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, metaprogramming

I have an abstract class for comparable+hashable values:

```
class Key
{
public:
  virtual bool operator ==(const Key&) const = 0;
  virtual bool operator !=(const Key&) const = 0;
  virtual u32 hashcode() const = 0;
};
```

and some concrete class C which inherits this.

```
class C : public Key
{
private:
  u32 a, b;
public:
  static const C& null; // a prototype for representing a "no value" C
  // Some reasonable implementation; it's just a pair
  // ...
};
```

and I would like to implement a templated HashSet class:

```
template<class T inherits Key, const T& proto> class HashSet
{
  //...
};
```

T is the type of values stored in these sets. proto should be an instance of T which is used as the "null" value of type T for the purposes of set inclusion. I am reasonably experienced with C++ but not especially with TMP and, although it seems like something which should be embarrassingly simple to pull off, I cannot seem to figure out how something like my pseudo-code **"class T inherits Key"** is actually done in C++. I want to be able to create a hash-set of instances of C like:

```
HashSet<C, C::null> myset;
```

Can somebody please tell me what the proper and idiomatic way to handle this situation in C++ would be? Thank you!

Comment: [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

Comment: I will never understand why a `std::enable_if` hidden in a template parameter list of a primary template is preferred to a `static_assert` with a user-friendly message

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I would say it's a trade-off between a nicer error message and having the type constraints documented directly in the declaration rather than hidden in the definition.

Comment: Fortunately this will all be a moot point with Concepts.

Comment: What is the advantage of requiring this base class compared to simply expecting the functions to be there? You save on virtual functions and poor design. Want to use an int as a key? Sorry, can't do that. Did you just accidentally compare FooKey and BarKey? Sure, the compiler is just fine with that because the abstract function's interface allows it.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like relying on an implicit interface would be preferable to requiring inheritance.

Comment: @SebastianRedl - it is more modern, and more expressive by using the new cryptic syntax :P

Comment: Everything you've all pointed out is interesting. I actually hadn't realized I could simply allow it to fail after template instantiation, assuming the compiler would be smart enough not allow me to use Key's methods on T. I guess it is neither smart enough to check pre-instantiation, nor smart enough to allow me to do this nicely. I'll have to read about static_assert as well and play with this to see what I think is best here. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Thomas: You can always do a `static_assert<std::is_convertible<decltype(T()==T()), bool>::value, "T must be Comparable">`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `std::enable_if_t` and `std::is_base_of` for this:

```
template<class T, const T& proto, 
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Key,T>::value>* = nullptr> 
class HashSet
{
  //...
};
```

Now `HashSet` instantiations are only valid if `T` inherits from `Key`.

`std::enable_if_t` is a C++14 feature. You can use `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` if you're stuck with C++11.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a188ceffdfbdbbd7)

---

Another option would be to use `static_assert`:

```
template<class T, const T& proto>
class HashSet
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Key, T>::value, "T must inherit from Key");
};
```

This is maybe a bit clearer and gives you a more friendly error message, but your type constraint is no longer given in the class declaration.

---

With [Concepts](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf) we'll get clarity, better error messages and keep our constraints in the declaration:

```
template <class Base, class Derived>                                                                                                                                                                                                           
concept bool IsBaseOf = std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value;

template<class T, const T& proto>
requires IsBaseOf<Key,T>
class HashSet
{};
```

Comment: Wow, this is gross looking "improvement" in C++14... That's no comment on your answer of course. I appreciate the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty awful. As Piotr pointed out in the comments, you could use a `static_assert` in the class definition to gain a bit of clarity and a nicer error message at the expense of having your type constraints documented in your declaration.

Comment: @Thomas - that's the C++ way. A plot of a sinister cabal to turn the language in an atrocity to keep its adoption rate low, and the wages - high ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Can somebody please tell me what the proper and idiomatic way to handle this situation in C++ would be?

That would be simply not handling it. If the user passes in a type that derives from `Key`, then the template instantiation will work even if you don't add that as an explicit requirement in a code annotation. If the user passes in an invalid template argument, then things are expected to break.

The next version of C++ will likely have support for clearly including such annotations, but in the current version of C++, while there are some tricks you can use, except in limited circumstances the idiomatic way is to just not bother with it.

Comment: I would say that tricks like `std::enable_if` have become a de facto way of expressing type constraints to both the user and compiler, but I guess that's debatable.

Comment: @TartanLlama Yeah, I do agree with that, when type constraints are expressed then `std::enable_if` is the idiomatic way of doing that, but because it comes across as kind of a hack, expressing type constraints is something that simply isn't generally done yet, at least not from what I've seen. :)

Comment: Thanks hvd. I actually hadn't even realized it wouldn't complain unless I instantiated a template with a T not supporting the methods I used. I guess it's neither smart enough to check this, nor smart enough to let me do this elegantly, so... maybe it evens out. I'll play around with these solutions and check back. Much appreciated!